# How to get a count of rows qualified for clean-up in Change Tracking?

Tags: sql-server-2008, change-tracking

Is there a way to get a rowcount for clean-up in Change Tracking?

When I run the following command, I get the number of rows affected. However, I need this information, ahead of time.

```
sp_flush_CT_internal_table_on_demand [ @TableToClean= ] 'TableName'
```

Can I get this info from the system tables?

Comment: May I ask why? What are you going to do with the rowcount?

Comment: scsimon! 
You answered my previous question too. 

I recently noticed that the auto clean-up was not working. We got a severity 16 error. I had to run a clean-up script manually. 

I want to run some sort of proactive script to ensure auto clean-up is running.

Comment: I don't think that being able to capture the number of records which *should* be flushed prior to attempting to flush them would help here. Setting up an alert for that job, as you seem to have caught with the Severity 16, and investigating why it failed is the route i'd take.  This may be better asked on dba.stackexchange.com though

Comment: That makes sense. I guess, I can come-up with a process to mine the log for these severity alerts, and take it from there. 

Thank you so much. 

btw: I get confused with stackoverflow & stackexchange. wonder why they created 2 similar sounding websites.

Comment: stackexchange is the overarching network to encompass all the different sites. I think stackoverflow was the original though, and thus they never changed the name. Ill post an answer on how to do that (the alert)

Comment: ok. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many good blogs on a bunch of alerts you should have set up by default. [**Here is one**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3384/configuring-critical-sql-server-alerts/), and [**here is another**](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/configure-sql-server-alerts/). This will prevent you from searching the error log for certain messages pertaining to this severity. However, it will alert you for any application or code that raises this severity and 16 is very common so you *may* not want to add that level to an alert. I'd add 19-25 though as well as other specified error messages contained in those blogs (823, 824, 825, 829, 832, 855, 856).

To only be notified when that job fails, you can just add a notification on the job to alert you when it fails. First you will [**need to set up an operator**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1523/how-to-setup-sql-server-alerts-and-email-operator-notifications/) so you can get emails, and then you'll just want to [**enable the notification on the job**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/notify-an-operator-of-job-status?view=sql-server-2017). If you do want to scan the error log for specific text though, I created a script that'll do just that. You can find it on [**GitHub here**](https://github.com/scsimon/sqlserver/blob/master/usp_error_log), and while it was designed to send daily emails with error log results, it can be ran adhoc.